# Is there better way to check if all entries of a list is in another?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have something like this:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = ['a','t','g','c','b']
```

and:

```
def check_list(a, b):
    for entry in a:
        if entry not in b:
            return False
    return True
```

How to do this well?

Comment: Making use of a `set` would speed things up if duplicates aren't a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`set.issubset`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> b = ['a','t','g','c','b']
>>> set(a).issubset(b)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the set operators:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> b = ['a','t','g','c','b']
>>> set(a) <= set(b)
True
```

If you need to handle duplicates aswell:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> cb = Counter(b)
>>> cb.subtract(Counter(a))
>>> all(count >= 0 for count in cb.values())
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['a', 't', 'g', 'c', 'b']

print(all(item in b for item in a))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Fails for `a = [2]`, `b = [1, 2, 3]`